# Merging two lists of different type objects

Tags: java, algorithm, merge

I am having two lists of two different types of objects, which share some properties. Let us say List usersDb, and List usersLdap.
They share one property - userId. I want to merge usersDb and usersLdap into one list of another type of object (using some data from one list and some from second one). Important thing is that lists may be of different sizes. Then, that data should also be in final list, but fields from list that they did not occur in should remail null.

Comment: I would start by turning each list into a map by the common userId property. Then go through all the ids and build your objects for the final list

Comment: have you even tried some code? please share It.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could look like something like this (map the lists by user id, get all the user ids - or get the intersections of user ids, then go over all the user ids, get the matching value in each map, create your third type):

```java
List<UserDb> listA = ...;
List<UserLdap> listB = ...;

Map<String, UserDb> a = listA.stream().collect(toMap(UserDb::getUserId, Function.identity());
Map<String, UserDb> b = listB.stream().collect(toMap(UserLdap::getUserId, Function.identity());

Set<String> allIds = new HashSet<>();
allIds.addAll(a.keySet());
allIds.addAll(b.keySet()); // Or retainAll if you want the intersection instead of the union

List<FinalType> = allIds.stream().map(id -> {
    UserDb userDb = a.get(id);
    UserLdap userLdap = b.get(id);
    FinalType t = // Build this one from the 2 others. Be careful that either can be null
    return t;
}).collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would improve performance to transform one of the `List`s (let's say `List<UserLdap>`) to a `Map<String,UserLdap>` indexed by the userId (I assumed it's a `String`).

Now you can iterate over the other `List`, and for each element, search if the `Map` contains a matching element. Use those elements to create an instance of the merged type, and add to the output `List`.

Finally, you'll have to search the the `List` that was transformed to a `Map` for elements not having a corresponding element in the other `List`, transform them to the merged type, and add to the output `List`. For that final step to be efficient, it might be useful to create a `Set<String>` of all the userIds present in the other `List`.

Comment: @Lino Oh, sorry about that. A copy and paste error. Thanks!